# Strange printk effect on linux stack size testing

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, printk

```
I am trying to test linux kernel stack size in 64 bit.
```

I found this weird behaviour.
I wrote following code to crash the kernel but strange thing is that
 it crashes only if printk is uncommented,
otherwise runs fine with no errors/warnings!!.

```
    #include <linux/init.h>
    #include <linux/module.h>
    #include <linux/kernel.h>

    static int __init crash_stack_init(void)
    {
        long arr[1024];
        long *a;

        a = &arr[0];

        //printk("%p\n", &arr[0]);

        return 0;
    }

        enter code here

    static void __exit crash_stack_exit(void)
    {
    }

    module_init(crash_stack_init);
    module_exit(crash_stack_exit);


Here is the "make" output without the printk,
```

> make -C /lib/modules/4.4.0-53-generic/build
>   M=/home/naveenvc/work/ker/crash_stack modules
>       make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-53-generic'
>         CC [M]  /home/naveenvc/work/ker/crash_stack/crash_stack.o
>         Building modules, stage 2.
>         MODPOST 1 modules
>         CC      /home/naveenvc/work/ker/crash_stack/crash_stack.mod.o
>         LD [M]  /home/naveenvc/work/ker/crash_stack/crash_stack.ko
>       make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-53-generic'

```
And make output with printk,
```

> make -C /lib/modules/4.4.0-53-generic/build
>   M=/home/naveenvc/work/ker/crash_stack modules make[1]: Entering
>   directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-53-generic'   CC [M] 
>   /home/naveenvc/work/ker/crash_stack/crash_stack.o
>   **> /home/naveenvc/work/ker/crash_stack/crash_stack.c: In function
>   ‘crash_stack_init’:
>   /home/naveenvc/work/ker/crash_stack/crash_stack.c:14:1: warning: the
>   frame size of 8200 bytes is larger than 1024 bytes
>   [-Wframe-larger-than=]  }  ^**
>   Building modules, stage 2.   MODPOST 1
>   modules   CC
>   /home/naveenvc/work/ker/crash_stack/crash_stack.mod.o   LD [M] 
>   /home/naveenvc/work/ker/crash_stack/crash_stack.ko make[1]: Leaving
>   directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-53-generic'

What could be causing this?

Comment: Surely printk() uses some stack too, so the combined stack usage of your function + printk becomes too much

Comment: the compliant is not about total stack use (which would be just above half of the allowed size), but the use of that particular function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stack size is well documented and the above is not the right way to test, in particular in older kernels which used hugepages to back the stack the aforementioned code would jump over to the next stack.

The func __crash_stack_init with prink commented out is a leaf function - it does not call anything, so the compiler knows exactly what happens with local vars. In particular in this code it sees the full array is not needed and thus its not being allocated. However, the call to printk passes arr in. The compiler does not know what the func is going to do with it, thus it has to reserve 1024 * sizeof(long) on the stack which results in the warning.

Stacks got bumped to 16KB years ago, you can start reading here https://lwn.net/Articles/600644/

Comment: Looks like GCC is too smart. It won't allocate memory for the array unless its actually used. 
Even initialising the array or passing to a  local function won't matter. 
Since printk actually need to print the value passed to it, GCC was allocating the array.

Disabling the optimisation for the function with "__attribute__ ((optimize("O0")))" will also produce warning without printk.